# Invoke string GenericMethod<T>() without specifying T

Tags: c#, generics, delegates

I have a method with a signature

```
string GenericMethod<T>();
```

Usually you'd call this simply with:

```
var result = GenericMethod<AType>();
```

However, that doesn't work for my case because `AType` is passed to the parent method as a `Type`.

There's code below which shows where I've got to. Currently it errors as //ERROR HERE.

Before the code, quick explanation: `TestClass` implements both `ITestClass` and `INotTestClass`. This is important because the point here is, if I am passed a `TestClass`, I would want to invoke the method with `ITestClass`, not `INotTestClass`. 
`TestClass` has a method that simply returns the name of the type in its generic brackets.

Ok, here's the code in the form of a Unit test.

```
using System;
using NUnit.Framework;

namespace Ian.Tests
{   
    [TestFixture]
    public class MiscTests
    {
        [Test]
        public void WhoWeCallingTest()
        {
            var i = new TestClass();
            i.TestGetTheType();
        }
    }

    public class TestClass : ITestClass, INotTestClass
    {
        public void TestGetTheType()
        {
            var t1 = typeof(ITestClass);
            var t2 = typeof(INotTestClass); 

            var t = GetType();

            // so I can make a delegate normally, but no use as I don't have this info usually.
            var dummyFunc = new MyDelegate<ITestClass>(GetTheType<ITestClass>);


            var methodInfo = t.GetMethod("GetTheType");
            var baseType = typeof(MyDelegate<>);
            var delType = baseType.MakeGenericType(t1);
            //ERROR HERE.
            var del = Delegate.CreateDelegate(delType, this, methodInfo);
            del.Method.Invoke(this, null);

        }

        public delegate string MyDelegate<T>();

        public string GetTheType<T>()
        {
            return typeof(T).Name;
        }
    }

    public interface ITestClass { }

    public interface INotTestClass { }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [MethodInfo.MakeGenericMethod](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodinfo.makegenericmethod%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to construct the appropriate method:

```
var methodInfo = t.GetMethod("GetTheType");
var methodWithType = methodInfo.MakeGenericMethod(t1);
methodWithType.Invoke(this, null);
```

Comment: That works, didn't occur to me to look on the methodInfo for a make generic method :)

Answer (score 0):

I must admit I do not fully understand your requirements, but in this particular case isn't a simple check sufficient?

```
if(this is ITestClass)
    return this.GetTheType<ITestClass>();
else if(this is INotTestClass)
    return this.GetTheType<INotTestClass>();
else 
    throw new InvalidOperationException // or whatever
                ("unexpected type: " + this.GetType());
```

Comment: if you insist on using generics, Reed Copsey is right: you can't use CreateDelegate with a MethodInfo parameter that contains unbound type parameters, and besides it doesn't match the delegate type in 'delType'

Comment: Hi Staafl, the problem is the if statement would end up with a thousand interfaces in it, some of which I don't know about :)